# Why are position measurements required to measure spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics

In all the instances that I can imagine, it seems that measuring spin involves a position measurement in one way or the other. For instance, in the stern gerlach experiment, we have an entanglement between the spin and the spatial degrees of freedom, after the particle moves through the in-homogeneous magnetic field, as could be derived from the nature of the interaction Hamiltonian $H=\mu.\hat{\sigma}\vec B $.  We then do a projective position measurement to infer about the spin.
I am wondering if there are methods by which we could directly measure spin, without having to make position measurement(not even on an ancillary system, which we somehow entangle with our system of concern)? Or is such indirect measurability a feature of spin observable?

I see that this question is related(more specific version of), but not identical to

[How is anything *not* ultimately a position measurement?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145283/how-is-anything-not-ultimately-a-position-measurement)

Comment: Another indirect method to measure spin of an electron in an atom is to do a spectroscopy. But at the end of the day every measurement fundamentally will be of position (in this case, of the photon).